# framework not found issue when linking a framework within a framework

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, frameworks

I have a framework(FRAME1) that includes versions a b and c this is then included as a dependency within another framework(FRAME2).

However when I build FRAME2 it dies out with: `ld:framework not found <nameofframework>`

I have made the install location of the frame1 to /Library/Frameworks and I have also set it as @rpath

however frame2 still errors out.  I have hard coded the framework search paths and that also doesnt change the situation.

here is the xcode error output:

```
Ld build/Release/TSVideoAppKit.framework/Versions/B/TSVideoAppKit normal i386
cd /Users/benb/Projects/Telestream/swRelease/Pipeline/2.6/Dib/Code/Macintosh/Frameworks/TSVideoAppKit
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
/Xcode3/usr/bin/g++-4.0 -arch i386 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Xcode3/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/benb/Projects/Telestream/swRelease/Pipeline/2.6/Dib/Code/Macintosh/Frameworks/TSVideoAppKit/build/Release -F/Users/benb/Projects/Telestream/swRelease/Pipeline/2.6/Dib/Code/Macintosh/Frameworks/TSVideoAppKit/build/Release -filelist /Users/benb/Projects/Telestream/swRelease/Pipeline/2.6/Dib/Code/Macintosh/Frameworks/TSVideoAppKit/build/TSVideoAppKit.build/Release/TSVideoAppKitFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/TSVideoAppKit.LinkFileList -install_name /Library/Frameworks/TSVideoAppKit.framework/Versions/B/TSVideoAppKit -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Library/Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework TSPipelineEngine -framework Cocoa -framework CoreVideo -framework OpenGL -framework QTKit -framework QuickTime -framework CoreAudio -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -o /Users/benb/Projects/Telestream/swRelease/Pipeline/2.6/Dib/Code/Macintosh/Frameworks/TSVideoAppKit/build/Release/TSVideoAppKit.framework/Versions/B/TSVideoAppKit

ld: framework not found TSPipelineEngine
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Xcode3/usr/bin/g++-4.0 failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I have looked at this but it didnt seem to help: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/

Comment: Sorry, but your question is just too hard to understand. Please provide real examples, instead of foo, bar, and write the complete linker error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was Xcode 3.2.6.  If I down reved to 3.2.5 it worked.  I have logged a bug against apple in their Radar system.

Problem ID: 10139645